# Не получается склонировать проект GitLab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

Пытаюсь склонировать проект, командой `git clone git@gitlab.com:вот эта вот штука с гитлаба`, вылезает ошибка

```
  ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Network is unreachable
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
```

Решений не нашёл, как можно решить данную проблему? Публичный ssh-rsa сгенерировал, в гитлаб вставил.

Comment: Какой именно репозиторий пытаетесь клонировать?

Comment: *ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: **Network is unreachable*** — где-то блокируются обращения: провайдер, ваша локальная сеть, ваш компьютер. вот в каком-то из указанных мест и «найдёте решение».

Comment: если «найденное решение» находится не в вашем компьютере, а в вашей локальной сети или в провайдере, можете попробовать [запасной вариант как раз для подобных случаев](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/)

Comment: спасибо большое